# I get this error " Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character stri when I insert data into my table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I created the following table and when I try to insert data

```
INSERT INTO ORDR 
VALUES ('OID3', 'S0574', 'C124', 'Capricos', 'Item7', '2016-sep-13', 2, 'Cash', 3, 'Approved', 'Deliver', 'phone', NULL, 12);
```

I get this error

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

My table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE ORDR 
(
     OrderID CHAR(8) PRIMARY KEY, 
     staffID CHAR(5),
     CustomerId CHAR(5),
     foodName VARCHAR(15),
     ItemCode CHAR(5),
     date DATE, 
     tax INTEGER, 
     PaymentMethod VARCHAR(10),
     totalAmount INTEGER, 
     paymentApproved CHAR(8),
     Status VARCHAR(10),
     Description VARCHAR(12),
     bankName CHAR(5),
     bankCode INTEGER,

     FOREIGN KEY(ItemCode) 
         REFERENCES MenueItem (ItemCode) 
         ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE NO ACTION,
     FOREIGN KEY(staffID) 
         REFERENCES Staff (staffID) 
         ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE NO ACTION,
     FOREIGN KEY(CustomerId) 
         REFERENCES Customer (CustomerId) 
         ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You may notice `convert(date,'2016-sep-13')` which returns `2016-09-13`

```
INSERT INTO ORDR VALUES ('OID3', 'S0574','C124','Capricos', 'Item7' ,convert(date,'2016-sep-13'),2,'Cash', 3,'Approved' ,'Deliver', 'phone',NULL,12);
```

If you are on 2012+, you may want `try_convert()`.  Even with a bogus date, it won't fail, but will produce a `NULL`.

Comment: Thank you for your help.